# Objective-C: make reference to class that created class

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Being mysef a newbie to Obj-C I´m having some troubles creating a navigation scheme.

Well, I have this NavigationController with its UIViewController (let's call it `mainView`).

Inside the ViewController I load another UIViewController (let's call it `dynaView`, I add it with `insertSubview:dynaView.view`).

The Controller for `dynaView` has a `NavigationController pushViewController` to another ViewController, but since the NavigationController is related to `mainView`, using `self.NavigationController pushViewController` won't do the trick, so I was wondering how can I make reference to the NavigationController of the mainView instance that created dynaView?

Something like `self.parent.NavigationController...`

Anyone who can help me :) ?

Comment: you're structure sounds horrible, why don't you just add the dynaView by pushing it from your root controller?

Comment: I know it is not the most goodlooking, but It was the only way I could manage to make this dude works

Comment: let's not call a controller (UIViewController) a view (mainView) - it's much more standard to include "controller" in the variable name when it's a controller.

Answer (score 3):

UIView has a superview property; UIViewController has a parentViewController property. One of those is what you're looking for.

Comment: Just to clarify, you can access this property through `[self superview]`, or `[aView superview]`.

Comment: `self superview`does not work, what I've done that do is `self.superview`. Is that OK or am I missing something? Besides, I guess for this, `parentViewController`is the one I should be using, since I'm pushing a ViewController

Comment: Mmmh. I Think superview nor parentViewController will work since `mainView`and `dynaView`are separate controllers (`dynaView.view` is added with `insertSubview`).